# A Designer Virus

Tags: virology, biotechnology

An [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulip_mania) at Wikipedia describes color changes that viruses have produced in tulips (without any human intention). And another [article](http://phys.org/news/2015-04-harmless-artificial-virus-gene-therapy.html) (elsewhere on the web) describes viruses that were designed to fight diseases in people. This makes me wonder:

Would it be possible to design a virus to produce certain coloration in tulips -- for example, if I want tulips to have white petals with blue streaks? Would this create a new strain of tulips that propagate that coloration without further human interference?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: @another 'Homo sapien' In response to your comment I enhanced the question yesterday.